How to debug layouts on compose desktop (compose multiplatform)? Is there a layout inspector for desktop?
On Android, I can use the layout inspector in Android Studio to debug my layouts. How does one debug their layout in compose desktop? I couldn't find a layout inspector for desktop.
I'm using IntelliJ for compose desktop. Is @Preview annotation the only debug tool available for compose multiplatform?
